# Is there a way to tell how many messages are in channel buffer?

Tags: go

I have identified a bottleneck in my program, it is a buffered channel. I would like to give client an indication of system load, which should be indicated by number of messages buffered in the channel.

Is there a way in Go to tell how many buffered messages there are in a channel?

If you also have a Java background, I am looking for an equivelent of this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#size()

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> [Length and capacity](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity)
>
> The built-in functions `len` and `cap` take arguments of various types
>   and return a result of type `int`. The implementation guarantees that
>   the result always fits into an `int`.
>
> ```
> Call      Argument type    Result
>
> len(s)    chan T           number of elements queued in channel buffer
>
> cap(s)    chan T           channel buffer capacity
> ```

The `len` function for a channel gives the number of elements queued in the channel buffer. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 8)
    ch <- 42
    ch <- 7
    <-ch
    ch <- 64
    // number of queued elements = 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 = 2
    fmt.Println(len(ch), cap(ch))
}
```

Output:

```
2 8
```

Comment: @igonejack: They are goroutine safe and, therefore, thread safe.

Answer (score -2):

There is an alternative solution to this using a "queue" process that handles the queueing of messages and also is able to report on its size. For this you will need an input channel and an output channel, plus a query channel through which the size is obtained. Because there will be two input channels, you will need a select (a CSP 'choice') between them.

Here's a [**little demo**](http://play.golang.org/p/es1ooOna7L) of this in operation. The queue consists of a slice as a buffer and an input channel.

```
func queue(in <-chan string, out chan<- string, query <-chan chan int) {
    buffer := []string{}
    var s string
    var reply chan int
    for {
        // Go select doesn't support boolean guards so we need the 'if' outside the select instead
        if len(buffer) > 0 {
            select {
            case reply = <-query:
                reply <- len(buffer)
            case s = <-in:
                buffer = append(buffer, s)
            case out <- buffer[0]:
                buffer = buffer[1:]
            }
        } else {
            select {
            case reply = <-query:
                reply <- len(buffer)
            case s = <-in:
                buffer = append(buffer, s)
            }
        }
    }
}
```